# Unexpected Font Change in Header When Compiling LaTeX Document Locally with TeX Live

Tags: header-footer

I'm using the ctexart document class for my LaTeX document. Recently, I noticed that the font of the header in my document has changed from the default KaiTi (楷体) to SongTi (宋体). I haven't made any changes to the format file (.cls), only added content to the main document (.tex). When I compile the same document on Overleaf, the header displays in KaiTi as expected. However, when I compile locally using TeX Live, the header is always in SongTi. I'm wondering if this could be a system bug or if there's something else causing this issue. Here's an excerpt from my active file for reference.

Comment: Without [knowing, what you are doing](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) and what the log file says about the loaded fonts,  I can only guess, that there are different fonts installed on Overleaf and your local system.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue ...